# Why is Envers deleting new record after reading REVINFO

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

My current project is using Hibernate Envers for auditing tables. I have an entity declared as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONFIG")
@Audited()
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Configuration extends DetailedAuditEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "config_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "config_sequence", sequenceName = "CONFIG_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;

    // other columns

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // equals override
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // hashcode override
    }
}
```

This works fine on my local setup, and I am able to insert and update records using the JPARepository's `.save()` function. However, after this code was deployed to SIT, the testing team raised an issue where after they create a new configuration, the system displays the "Record created successfully" message, but they cannot see the new configuration in the table of records.

So I dug through the SIT logs, and this is what I found (I removed a bunch of the columns to make it more readable).

```
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: insert into CONFIG (ACTION, IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS, STATUS, CONFIG_CATEGORY, VERSION, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: insert into REVINFO (REVTSTMP) values (?)
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: insert into CONFIG_AUD (REVTYPE, ACTION, IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS, STATUS, CONFIG_CATEGORY, ID, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: select con0_.ID as ID1_183_0_, con0_.REV as REV2_183_0_, defaultrev1_.REV as REV1_13_1_, con0_.REVTYPE as REVTYPE3_183_0_, con0_.ACTION as ACTION4_183_0_, con0_.IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS as IS_SAGA_5_183_0_, con0_.STATUS as STATUS6_183_0_, con0_.CONFIG_CATEGORY as CONFIG_CA26_183_0_, defaultrev1_.REVTSTMP as REVTSTMP2_13_1_ from CONFIG_AUD con0_ cross join REVINFO defaultrev1_ where con0_.REVTYPE<>? and con0_.ID=? and con0_.REV=(select max(con2_.REV) from CONFIG_AUD con2_ where con2_.ID=? and con2_.ID=con0_.ID) and con0_.REV=defaultrev1_.REV order by con0_.REV asc
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: select con0_.ID as ID1_182_0_, con0_.ACTION as ACTION2_182_0_, con0_.IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS as IS_SAGA_3_182_0_, con0_.STATUS as STATUS4_182_0_, con0_.CONFIG_CATEGORY as SCUP_CA24_182_0_, con0_.VERSION as VERSION26_182_0_ from CONFIG con0_ where con0_.ID=?

Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: delete from CONFIG where ID=? and VERSION=?
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: insert into REVINFO (REVTSTMP) values (?)
Aug 19 06:25:32 IEXBIZSVC02 java[19539]: Hibernate: insert into CONFIG_AUD (REVTYPE, ACTION, IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS, STATUS, CONFIG_CATEGORY, ID, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The way I read that was:

1. Hibernate inserts the new record.
2. Hibernate then joins REVINFO table to check for... something?
3. Hibernate then deletes the record that was just inserted (I'm guessing this is supposed to be their version of a rollback?).

The CONFIG_AUD table confirms my interpretation, with both an insert and a delete record right after.

Why is Envers deleting the new record after insertion? What did it find that triggered the apparent rollback? And if there is a problem with the insertion that required a rollback, shouldn't hibernate have thrown an exception instead of returning successfully?

This issue only exists on the SIT build. I've been consulting with my other colleagues, but none of them have any idea. I cannot reproduce it on my local development setup (it works perfectly here). Could it be a configuration problem?

**Additional info:**
The REVINFO table is the default one that Envers creates, with just a REV and REVTSTMP column.

Comment: Could you supply your equals/hashCode implementations?  Also are there any other mappings of importance in `Configuration` beyond basic columns?  Fwiw, Envers does not ever perform a _delete_ operation unless there is a need for a rollback which happens in only a very unique and highly unlikely situation here.  So my guess is it could be something in the code causing this.  Can you pin point where in your code this happens as well and post that?

Comment: As a second follow-up, Envers never modifies the main data tables - ever.  It only ever inserts or updates the audit tables, so if you're seeing something happening with the main data tables as a part of a transaction, then there is something that is causing the entity to be removed from the persistence context.  Since Envers sees that as a delete event raised by ORM, that means its something outside of Envers which is triggering that and has nothing to do with the audit framework directly.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. This does seem to mesh with what our offshore team working on the application framework is saying. They posited that it has to do with our custom workflow implementation so I'm verifying that right now. To answer your question about delete operations, my application logic does not utilize hard deletes, so `.delete()` is never called, which made this problem all the more confounding. As an aside for educational purposes, what is the "unique and highly unlikely" situation that would cause Envers to trigger a rollback?

Comment: Whenever work units get prepared in Envers, we may need to merge it with other work units for the same entity as we want to capture a full _snapshot_ of an entity change during a transaction rather than each individual change.  For example, you insert a row and then update it during the same transaction.  There is a corner case where you can perform certain entity operations and should that merge fail, Envers will issue a delete.  But its worth mentioning that such delete operations are only on the _AUD tables, which isn't what your use case is.